# How to delete a paticular Object in an array inRethinkDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rethinkdb

I am Just trying to learn RethinkDB.I am little Bit Confused That how to delete an single Object in an array,What is the Exact query I have to use if i have to delete this Object

```
 {
        "name":  "Ram" ,
        "username":  "B97bf210-c4d2d-11e6-b783-07b5fev048705"
        }
```

from whoLikedIt Array
My data

```
        {
        "comments": [ ],
        "id":  "c242c74d-03d9-4963-9a22-4779facb8192" ,
       .....
        "views": 0 ,
        "whoLikedIt": [
        {
        "name":  "Vignesh Warar" ,
        "username":  "d97bf210-c42d-11e6-b783-07b5fe048705"
        },
{
        "name":  "Ram" ,
        "username":  "B97bf210-c4d2d-11e6-b783-07b5fev048705"
        },


        ]
    .....
        }
```

My Try

```
r.db('image').table('posts').get('c242c74d-03d9-4963-9a22-4779facb8192').update(
  {whoLikedIt:r.row('whoLikedIt').filter({username:"B97bf210-c4d2d-11e6-b783-07b5fev048705"}).delete()}
)
```

Throws Me a error

```
e: Cannot nest writes or meta ops in stream operations.  Use FOR_EACH instead in:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
r.db('image').table('posts').get('c242c74d-03d9-4963-9a22-4779facb8192').update(function(row) {
  return {whoLikedIt: row('whoLikedIt').filter(function(obj) {
    return obj('username').ne("B97bf210-c4d2d-11e6-b783-07b5fev048705");
  })};
})
```